# Invalid Relative URL after upgrading from .Net3.5 to .Net4

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, .net-4.0

My application is written in VB.Net running on .Net3.5
After upgrading to .Net4, I noticed that some of the hyperlinks that previously worked correctly now point to invalid locations, whereas other links that seem to be structured in the same way continue to work okay.

Breaking Link

```
<a id="aLeadId" runat="server" href="../leads.aspx">Link</a>
```

File is in *site/reports/revenue.aspx*
Should point to *localhost/site/leads.aspx* but instead points to *localhost/leads.aspx*

So my questions is, what is it about .NET4 that is causing these links to break, or is the upgrade a red herring and it is actually something else.
Adding an absolute link in the server side is how I will likely fix it, but I wanted to understand what had changed and caused it to break.

Comment: seems adding that still causes the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think that related to to changes made in some control rendering in Asp 4.0. You can try setting

```
<system.web> 
  <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5"/> 
</system.web>
```

in your web.config and check if it helps. To see to list of major changes in asp 4.0 go to: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes

Comment: Adding that into the web.config doesn't seem to change this.